# Tom should be awake

Tags: modal-verbs

a. It is not late at all. Tom must still be awake.

b. It is not late at all. Tom still has to be awake.

c. It is not late at all. Tom should still be awake.

The idea is that the speaker is deducing from the fact that it is not late that Tom is still awake.

Which of the sentences could be used in that context?

I find (b) a little off. It seems to carry the idea of duty. (c) seems more tentative than (a).

Comment: All modals can have either _deontic_ (about how the world is, including obligations) or _epistemic_ (about our knowledge of the world) meanings. _Have to_ is perhaps less commonly used epistemically than the rest, but it is still used that way.

Answer (score 2):

In ordinary speech, they are often used interchangeably, and a particular nuance or shade of meaning may be implied by the context, tone of voice, etc, but these observations may be useful:

> a. It is not late at all. Tom **must** still be awake.

Strong logical deduction from what I know about Tom, e.g. it is 22:00 and he never goes to bed/sleep before 23:00

> b. It is not late at all. Tom still **has** to be awake.

Often the same as (a) but sometimes expresses strong hope or necessity, e.g. Tom [just] has to be awake, because I need his signature on an urgent document.

> c. It is not late at all. Tom **should** still be awake.

Likely probability based on what I know about Tom, e.g. it is 22:00 and he usually goes to bed/sleep after 23:00 but sometimes earlier.